# Angular data-grid (ag-grid) sideBar is not working

Tags: angular

data-grid.component.html

```
<ag-grid-angular  style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" [sideBar]='true' [ngClass]="isEditable ? 'edit-table' : 'table'" class="ag-theme-balham"  [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
```

data-grid.component.ts
    import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

```
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';
import { PropertyKeys } from "ag-grid/dist/lib/propertyKeys";
import { ColDefUtil } from "ag-grid/dist/lib/components/colDefUtil";
// fix wrong property warning
PropertyKeys.ALL_PROPERTIES.push("__ob__");
ColDefUtil.ALL_PROPERTIES.push("__ob__");
```

Please check the below error.

Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'sideBar' since it isn't a known property of 'ag-grid-angular'.
1. If 'ag-grid-angular' is an Angular component and it has 'sideBar' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ag-grid-angular' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. (" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    
    ][sideBar]='true' [ngClass]="isEditable ? 'edit-table' : 'table'" class="ag-theme-balham"  [gridOption"): ng:///AppModule/DataGridComponent.html@34:58
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:486)

Comment: Can you create stackblitz link to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

As the error said the grid doesn't recognize this property (sideBar) and this because you're using an old version of ag-grid (<19).

**For the old version you should use 'showToolPanel' instead of 'sideBar'.**

You can read [ag-grid changelog for version 19.0.0](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/?fixVersion=19.0.0)

Also be aware for this (as they described):

> "The NPM package name for the free module of ag-Grid is now
>   ag-grid-community instead of ag-grid. This means you install with npm
>   install ag-grid-community and then you reference like import {Grid,
>   GridOptions} from "ag-grid-community"."